# Visual Studio 2005 - Projects disappearing

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs, resharper

Hmmm, a new odd issue that has just started. Every now and then VS drops a whole bunch of projects from the solution. It will say at the top of Solution explorer "42 projects" when it is displaying only about 20 or so. Closing VS and re-opening it fixes this, although it is a bit of a pain as it takes a little while for the .sln to open again.

We run VS2005 and mainly work on a 42 project solution targetting the Compact Framework 2.00. I'm pretty much the only one using Resharper here (despite my recommendations to others and their occasional oOoing and ahhing at its beauty) so i use CTRL+T to find classes but when i've been hitting SHFT + ALT + L to select the item in the solution explorer (to view the history in TFS) it hasn't matched anything which is how i've noticed this issue.

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Completely side note:  Resharper with a 42 project solution?  Ever have issues with performance, especially with intellisense?

Comment: No, intellisense is actually okay it's start up performance that kills which is a combination of opening it, resharper initialising and TFS dragging its knuckles. I have to open 2 of these (branch and trunk) and then I have to wait like 8 mins +. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this question is super old now and according to my old self:

> I think I just rebooted or something and I haven't seen the issue again.

This seems to be about as close as we'll ever get to a solution so I'll set this as the accepted answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't address your problem directly, have you considered breaking it up into multiple solutions? I'd imagine VS chokes when it starts to get that large, and you're probably working in an un-tested (though not un-supported, I suppose) situation, since I doubt the MS testers created a solution holding 40 projects, all targeting CF.NET.

If you can break it up, that's what I'd advise, and I'll bet the problem goes away. Also, have you tried installing the Service Pack for VS? If not, [here it is](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb4a75ab-e2d4-4c96-b39d-37baf6b5b1dc&DisplayLang=en).